# Where can I get "serviceAccountCredentials.json" for Firebase Admin?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-admin-privileges) is said what I need to set up Firebase on java:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com")
    .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

But where can I get **serviceAccountCredentials.json** ?

**UPDATED:**
I found that this file seems should have this fields, but where get this values?

```
{
  "type": "",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Found details about this in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk_in_non-google_environments)

[UPDATED 30.11.2021]

> To **generate a private key file** for your service account:
>
> In the Firebase console, open Settings > [Service Accounts](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk).
>
> Click Generate New Private Key, then confirm by clicking Generate Key.
>
> Securely store the JSON file containing the key.
>
> When authorizing via a service account, you have two choices for
> providing the credentials to your application. You can either set the
> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, or you can
> explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code. The first
> option is more secure and is strongly recommended.

**NB: When you generate a new private key, the old key will stop working immediately**

To create the a new private key file you need to go to this link

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/**YOUR_PROJECT**/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk
```

[OLD]

Quote from [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup):

> 2. Navigate to the [Service Accounts](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) tab in your project's settings page.
> 3. Click the **Generate New Private Key** button at the bottom of the **Firebase Admin SDK** section of the **Service Accounts** tab.
>
> After you click the button, a JSON file containing your service
> account's credentials will be downloaded. You'll need this to
> initialize the SDK in the next step.
>
> *Warning: Use extra caution when
> handling service account credentials in your code. Do not commit them
> to a public repository, deploy them in a client app, or expose them in
> any way that could compromise the security of your Firebase project.*
>
> This file is only generated once. If you lose or leak the key, you can
> repeat the instructions above to create a new JSON key for the service
> account.

Comment: Where should the JSON file be kept?

Comment: @xaunlopez anywhere in your project sources, or on your own server side, just put path the file ".setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))"

Comment: project sources isn't good because can't check into version control, and by server side do you mean firebase storage?? I am just using firebase firestore and cloud functions.

Comment: When you generate a new private key will the old key stop working immediately?

Comment: Has anyone understood if you generate a new private key wether the old key will stop working?

Comment: @perrosnk yes, it will stop working. `This file is only generated once. If you lose or leak the key, you can repeat the instructions above to create a new JSON key for the service account.`

Comment: If I have an existing firebase in the previous project, ant I go to the link above to get servicekey.json, it is my apiKey and the other credentials will be overwritten or still will be this same as before?

Comment: I clicked Generate Key and then the confirmation confirmation button and its not working.

Answer (score 19):

You can directly go to your **Firebase portal** --> **Project Settings** then **Service accounts**.
I made a tutorial that explain all the details : [How to get my Firebase Service Account Key file](https://clemfournier.medium.com/how-to-get-my-firebase-service-account-key-file-f0ec97a21620)