# how to get ClassPathResource in google cloudRun

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

I am following an [example](https://github.com/scsbatu/flutter-springboot/blob/master/springboot/src/main/java/com/example/springboot/SpringbootApplication.java) that does take [serviceAccount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799258/) , Application works fine when it is run locally. But when I try to deploy this application in Google Cloud Run ( gcloud run deploy --source . ) , it error out

The file firebase-adminsdk.json is present in src\main\resources
application.properties list it as

```
firebase.credential.resource-path=firebase-adminsdk.json
```

The error is

> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [void]: Factory method 'firebaseInitialization' threw
> exception;   nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
> path resource firebase-adminsdk.json] cannot be resolved to absolute
> file path because it does not reside in the file system:

Full Error is

> logName: "projects/projectXYZ/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstdout"
> receiveTimestamp: "2022-02-21T00:40:05.574893045Z" resource: {2}
> severity: "ERROR" textPayload:
> "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'firebaseInitialization' defined in
> com.example.helloworld.HelloworldApplication: Bean instantiation via
> factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [void]: Factory method 'firebaseInitialization' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
> path resource [firebase-adminsdk.json] cannot be resolved to absolute
> file path because it does not reside in the file system:
> jar:file:/workspace/target/helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/firebase-adminsdk.json
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> com.example.helloworld.HelloworldApplication.main(HelloworldApplication.java:26)
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
> ~[helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
> ~[helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
> ~[helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
> ~[helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [void]: Factory method 'firebaseInitialization' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
> path resource [firebase-adminsdk.json] cannot be resolved to absolute
> file path because it does not reside in the file system:
> jar:file:/workspace/target/helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/firebase-adminsdk.json
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     ... 28 common
> frames omitted Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path
> resource [firebase-adminsdk.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file
> path because it does not reside in the file system:
> jar:file:/workspace/target/helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/firebase-adminsdk.json
> at
> org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217)
> ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:154)
> ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> com.example.helloworld.HelloworldApplication.firebaseInitialization(HelloworldApplication.java:33)
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> com.example.helloworld.HelloworldApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b82b9488.CGLIB$firebaseInitialization$0()
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> com.example.helloworld.HelloworldApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b82b9488$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75044087.invoke()
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
> ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> com.example.helloworld.HelloworldApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b82b9488.firebaseInitialization()
> ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]     ... 29 common
> frames omitted" timestamp: "2022-02-21T00:40:05.466235Z" }

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile to the question

Comment: Look into application default credentials, so that you don't have to worry about service accounts at all. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-java

Comment: @puzzled Can you confirm if you have gone through my previous link and if your issue is resolved or not?

Comment: look https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#java_1